Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, problem 7.F.22
I'm trying to solve the following problem (from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", 4th edition, problem 22 of section 7F):

Suppose $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$. Let $n=\text{dim }V$ and let $s_1\geq \cdots \geq s_n$ denote the singular values of $T$. Prove that if $1\leq k \leq n$, then
$$\text{min}\{||T|_U||:U \text{ is a subspace of } V \text{ with dim }U = k\}=s_{n-k+1}.$$

In the above $V$ and $W$ are nonzero finite-dimensional inner product spaces and $||T|_U||=\text{max}\{||Tu||: u \in U \text{ and } ||u||\leq 1\}$ which is the greatest singular value of $T|_U$.
Assume there are $r$ positive singular values of $T$. By SVD there are orthonormal bases $e_1,\dots ,e_n$ and $f_1,\dots ,f_m$ of $V$ and $W$ respectively such that:
$$Te_j=\begin{cases}s_jf_j     &\text{if }1\leq j\leq r\\
                    0          &\text{if }r <j\leq n  \end{cases}$$
Choosing $U=\text{span}(e_{n-k+1},\dots,e_n)$ we have $\text{dim }U=k$ and $||T|_U||=s_{n-k+1}$. But I'm having trouble proving that for an arbitrary k-dimensional subspace $U$ we have $||T|_U||\geq s_{n-k+1}$ (except for the trivial cases where $k=1,n$), so any help would be appreciated.

Take the orthonormal bases that you mentioned in your question and set $W = \mathrm{span}(e_1, \dots, e_{n-k}, e_{n-k+1})$. This is a $(n-k+1)$-dimensional subspace of $V$. Now if we take ANY subspace $U$ of $V$ with dimension $k$, the intersection $U \cap W$ is a vector space of dimension at least $1$. This is due to the dimension formula
$$n = \dim V \ge \dim (U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim (U \cap W) = n+1 - \dim (U \cap W).$$
But this implies that there is a non-zero vector $v \in U \cap W$. Since it is in $W$ it is a linear combination of $e_1, \dots, e_{n-k+1}$. We scale it so that it has norm $1$. By orthonormality of the $e_i$ this is the case precisely if
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \lambda_i e_i$$
with $\sum \lambda_i^2 = 1$ (Pythagorean theorem). But then we have
$$||Tv||^2 = \left \lVert \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \lambda_i Te_i \right \rVert^2 = \left \lVert \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \lambda_i s_i f_i \right \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \lambda_i^2 s_i^2.$$
In the last step we used orthonormality of the $f_i$. Now since the singular values are ordered (and non-negative) this implies
$$||Tv||^2 \ge s_{n-k+1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} \lambda_i^2 = s_{n-k+1}^2.$$
This shows that $||T\vert_U|| \ge s_{n-k+1}$ for any $k$-dimensional subspace $U$ of $V$.
